# MS Word Pro Plus 2016 - Table of Contents alignment - unlike any I have ever seen

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016, table-of-contents

I am having trouble with my TOC for a document and have tried all solutions I know of including clearing all formatting and copying from other headings/styles, alignment of tabs and indents, and looking for hidden text and formatting but nothing has resolved this yet.

My TOC (see TOC snip) has Chapter 5 and Heading 5.2 all fine, but Heading 5.1 (should look exactly like 5.2) splits across two lines where the first line has no paragraph numbering but the correct heading and page number, and the second line has the correct paragraph numbering and page number but without the heading itself (which is on line 1 of course).

[TOC snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM6Gl.png)

The actual page that is being referred (see page snip) to has been cleared of formatting and reformatted and looks perfect but still no luck in the TOC.

[Page snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dQZm.png)

Hoping you can help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try copying and pasting your paragraph 5.2 heading (since that one works) to the right spot, and then replacing the copied text with your 5.1 heading text?

Comment: Wow - done!! I had not thought of that - I had copied and pasted the format, reformatted, re-styled but never thought to copy and write over the text!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Tanya](https://superuser.com/users/535106/tanya) for the answer:

"Maybe try copying and pasting your paragraph 5.2 heading (since that one works) to the right spot, and then replacing the copied text with your 5.1 heading text?"

It worked :)